# How to remove a file from Sharepoint with SQL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

### YES i know, that you'll never want to use SQL for changing data in Sharepoint.

I have a lot of files in my Sharepoint record center. 
I have one corrupted file that i can't delete.

I tried to delete with a solution, with powershell etc, so my last option is delete is from the database.

It's a test envirioment where i want it to use.

SQL is my last chance.......

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [SPContentDatabase.Repair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.repair.aspx) method?

You haven't stated what you attempted to do in your solution, Powershell script etc.  You might get other suggestions that might be less of a threat to your environment.

Answer (score 1):

All your items live in "AllUserData" table. It is, by the way, documented in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd358229(v=prot.13).aspx (surprise for me)
However, you will need the site id and list id of your item.